# How to catch correct resource among disambiguations / interrogate subresources in DBPedia using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikipedia, dbpedia, disambiguation

I have the title of a Youtube music video and I need to gather additional information from DBPedia like album, artist, release date, etc. I'd also like to get the 'abstract' of all these entities from DBPedia. I already use Musicbrainz to differentiate between song and artist in the title and it works rather well, except a few cases.

However my main problem is: when I pass the song to ask DBPedia (using a query with resource/{song}), sometimes I get no answer because {song} causes disambiguation. Example: resource/It's_My_Life has 11 disambiguates, 6 of which are songs. I need the resource "It's_My_Life_(Bon_Jovi_song)". How can I tell DBPedia that I need a resource of 'MusicalWork' type of a certain artist?

I tried in many ways to do this with SPARQL, but I always get an empty result and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. So far I was able to only get the abstract of every disambiguation, but I cannot get a specific property (like abstract) of a subresource of a disambiguation.

```
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/It's_My_Life>  dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?x .
    ?x dbo:abstract ?y .
}
```

I can't seem to go father than this. I tried with:

```
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/It's_My_Life>  dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?x .
    ?x dbo:MusicalArtist ?y .
    { SELECT ?z WHERE { 
        ?y dbo:abstract ?z}
    }
}
```

and

```
SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/It's_My_Life>  dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?x
    ?x rdfs:type ?y .
}
```

But results are always empty. How am I supposed to interrogate a subresource of a resource? Can anyone help me?

Comment: your second query is empty because it's wrong. I don't know what you want to get, but it `dbo:MusicalArtist` is not a property. `?x rdf:type dbo:MusicalArtist` would make more sense. But even then, why should it be of type `dbo:MusicalArtist`? It's clearly just of type `dbo:MusicalWork` or not?

Comment: anyways, a working query: `SELECT ?x ?y WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/It's_My_Life>  dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?x .
?x rdf:type dbo:MusicalWork.
    ?x dbo:abstract ?y .
filter(langmatches(lang(?y),'en'))
}`

Comment: @AKSW yes, I know the query is wrong, but I didn't know how to continue it properly. I wrongly typed 'dbo:MusicalArtist' there cause I forgot to keep into consideration that not all disambiguations are of MusicalWork type. Sorry, SPARQL is still rather confusing for me, I apologize. Your query works so I deeply thank you. I'll study it so I can better understand how SPARQL works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works now. And yes, SPARQL can be confusing sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, pulled from comments by @AKSW --

```
SELECT ?x ?y 
WHERE
  { 
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/It's_My_Life>  dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates  ?x              . 
    ?x                                          rdf:type                   dbo:MusicalWork . 
    ?x                                          dbo:abstract               ?y              . 
    FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG (?y), 'en' ) ) 
  }
```